# CA file disappeared after upgrading ubuntu packages

Tags: certificate-authority

I have ubuntu 12.04 server(s) that haven't been upgraded for 2 years. It's been working well and fine until we decided to upgrade it.

After upgrade (apt-get upgrade) CA file `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.crt` disappeared and program is not able to access to `Entrust Certification Authority - L1C`.

Any idea why this happen?

Here is the log:

`` ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ curl -i https://api.demo.com/ #works
ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ file /etc/ssl/certs/5f267794.0
/etc/ssl/certs/5f267794.0: symbolic link to `Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem'
ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ file /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem: symbolic link to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.crt'
ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ file /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.crt
/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.crt: PEM certificate
ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
root@ip-10-67-192-40:~# apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
ubuntu@ip-10-67-192-40:~$ curl -i https://api.demo.com/ #dosen't work ``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is the relevant changelog entry:

```
ca-certificates (20140927) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Update Mozilla certificate authority bundle to version 2.1.
  [...]
    The following certificate authorities were removed (-):
    - "Entrust.net Secure Server CA"
  [...]

 -- Michael Shuler <michael@pbandjelly.org>  Sat, 27 Sep 2014 15:14:00 -0500
```

A quick bit of DDGing and I've found [this mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622719) requesting removal, with a reference to [this other bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=617664) which suggests that the CA cert in question was deprecated, had all trust bits removed, and thus was removed from NSS.

Given that the cert was removed from NSS in 2011 (Firefox 6), and was presumably deprecated sometime before that, I'd say it's well past time to get a new certificate for the site you're trying to access.

Comment: This is very detailed answer, I own you a beer. 
The website that I'm trying to access is "https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/" .

It works well with chrome/firefox but not on ubuntu/debian OS. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Based on [this SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.xero.com), I get the impression that the Xero admins need to improve their SSL config overall, but the specific problem is that they're providing one chain (where the "Entrust 2048" cert is an intermediate), but *some* SSL clients are validating to an "Entrust 2048" cert that is self-signed and a root cert.  I'd contact Xero and tell 'em to up their game.

Answer (score 2):

> *Update:* It seems Xero is transitioning to a new certificate, which resolves this problem. The simple fix is to use **sha2-api.xero.com** instead of **api.xero.com**. But beware you'll need to change back by April 2016. More details: http://developer.xero.com/sha2-ssl-cert-migration-advisory-notice/

We were having the same problem connecting to **api.xero.com** on Ubuntu 14.04 servers using curl.

To elaborate on the previous answer, the solution is to install the *Entrust Secure Server CA* certificate manually to your CA certificate store. This is a (deprecated) root CA. The certificate can be downloaded from: https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_ssl_ca.cer

Download and place the file into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. Ensure it has a `.crt` extension (not the `.cer` it comes with).

Then run `sudo update-ca-certificates` to rebuild your system CA bundle.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but is it really wise to ignore the CA's deprecation of their certificate?

Comment: @FalconMomot As I see it, there are only two other possibilities: 1) Ask the other party to get a different certificate, and don't use the service until they do, or 2) disable peer validation. Number 1 is not an option for us, and number 2 is obviously terrible.

Comment: I note also that it's not clear the problem actually lies with Xero. The certificate for api.xero.com was issued in Feb 2015, so shouldn't be using a deprecated root - and it validates just fine in Firefox and Chrome browsers. In Firefox the validation path shows a different root CA, so there must be more to this problem than meets the eye.

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to use openssl s_client to fetch the certificate, inspect it with openssl x509, and see where the problem actually lies then.

Comment: Did already do that and found nothing untoward. But digging further, I suspect the problem is that the api.xero.com server is sending back an invalid intermediate CA chain - not an issue with the server cert itself. The chain they're supplying traces back to the deprecated Entrust cert, whereas the server cert itself traces a different path. OpenSSL appears to be trying to establish validity using the intermediate CA's supplied by the server, whereas Firefox ignores them.

Comment: Was going to report this issue to Xero when I discovered they are already in the process of transitioning to new SHA2-based certs which also fix this. Updated my answer.